# Pentaho 5.4 - The connection attemp failed (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, kettle

I'm working with Pentaho BI server 5.4. I've created some Kettle jobs with Spoon, uploaded them to the server and scheduled them via XAction files. Most of them work properly, but there is one that have one step that continues giving me the following error and stops the job execution:

```
2018-04-19 09:51:02,838 ERROR [org.pentaho.di] 2018/04/19 09:51:02 - Source.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : An error cause this step to stop: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
2018/04/19 09:51:02 - Source.0 - Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
2018/04/19 09:51:02 - Source.0 -
2018/04/19 09:51:02 - Source.0 - Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
2018/04/19 09:51:02 - Source.0 - The connection attempt failed.
2018-04-19 09:51:02,839 ERROR [org.pentaho.di] 2018/04/19 09:51:02 - DimOrigen.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Source]
```

The connection is made usign a JNDI. I know this JNDI works fine, because I'm using it in other transformations and they doesn't crash. In addition, this problem shows only in production environment and not in my machine; and only in some steps in the transformation (others use the same JNDI and doesn't give any error message).

The full stacktrace of the error is the following one:

```
2018-04-19 09:51:02,861 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.kettle.KettleComponent] Error Start: Pentaho Pentaho Open Source BA Server 5.4.0.1-130
2018-04-19 09:51:02,861 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.kettle.KettleComponent] 42ad3cc8-43ae-11e8-9bc0-0001a4a6a11b:COMPONENT:context-1888026901-1524127635683:0101-Transformation.xactionKettle.ERROR_0008 - [es_383] An unexpected error occurred running the transformation org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.kettle.KettleComponentException: Kettle.ERROR_0014 - [es_249] Error occurred during transformation execution
org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.kettle.KettleComponentException: Kettle.ERROR_0014 - [es_249] Error occurred during transformation execution
        at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.kettle.KettleComponent.executeJob(KettleComponent.java:1027)
        at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.kettle.KettleComponent.executeAction(KettleComponent.java:603)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.ComponentBase.execute(ComponentBase.java:465)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1186)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeAction(RuntimeContext.java:1151)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.performActions(RuntimeContext.java:1063)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeLoop(RuntimeContext.java:1013)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:895)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:797)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.executeInternal(SolutionEngine.java:352)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:282)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:179)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.XactionUtil.executeInternal(XactionUtil.java:311)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.XactionUtil.executeHtml(XactionUtil.java:201)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.XactionUtil.execute(XactionUtil.java:366)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.ActionSequenceContentGenerator.createContent(ActionSequenceContentGenerator.java:82)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SimpleContentGenerator.createContent(SimpleContentGenerator.java:60)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutput.generateContent(GeneratorStreamingOutput.java:236)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutput.write(GeneratorStreamingOutput.java:163)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.java:54)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.java:33)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
```

Has someone any idea about what's going on here?

Comment: The error message isn't very informative.  The database has its own log file. You could try 'tail'ing the PostgreSQL log file and watch it for errors when you execute the transformation. If the connection attempt does reach the server, you may find the error in PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no access to the database server logs.

Comment: Does your job try to access the same table for reading and writing ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I finally get managed to execute the transformation. It appears that there was other transformation executing at background dealing with the same tables and blocking them. I've rearranged the scheduled xD. Thanks for your interest.